# CSSTransition animation not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have an animation for a react component, which i can't get to run.

I think there's something wrong with the transitions, because if i just to an animation of the opacity it all works fine

I'm using the `CSSTransitionGroup` from `react-transition-group`

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
   transitionName="animate"
   transitionEnter={true}
   transitionEnterTimeout={700}
   transitionLeave={true}
   transitionLeaveTimeout={700} >
      {this.state.someState ? <Child key='animatedFormKey' handleChild={this.handleChild}/> : null}
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

My animation looks like this

```
.animate-enter {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);

}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: transform 700ms ease-in-out;
}
```

and the styling of the component it self is

```
.childComponent {
    position: fixed;
    height: 77%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 12;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example in jsfiddle/jsbin/codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, based on the code and without trying out code because you did not provide a test case, but `translate(A)` is the same as `translateX(A)`, and not the same as `translate(A, A)`. So you might want to try `transform: translate(0, 0);` instead in your `.animate-enter.animate-enter-active` rule.

Also, the transition property should be set on the initial element, so on `.animate-enter` and not on `.animate-enter.animate-enter-active`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same, but the result is the same :( The box just pops right up after the animation is done instead of getting animated

Comment: You are right about the transition property. Thanks :)